# React native fail to run-android even when emulator running

Tags: android, react-native

Running the command `react-native run-android` fails with the following output:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

The curious thing about this problem is that an emulator is running. `adb devices` returns

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

If these details help, its running in Linux, with the emulator set as Android 6.0 API Level 23, using Google APIs Intel Atom (x86).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one? I have the same issue.

Comment: Tl;dr no, didn't solve it, just abandoned the project. It seemed to only be a problem with one of project I was playing around with (https://github.com/vikeri/re-navigate). Thankfully it wasn't particularly important so I just abandoned it... Running a clean project worked fine. Sorry this doesn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just last week. I tried building the project thru Android Studio. I think one of the reasons of this error is that, the build looks for the updated (or compatible) version of the Gradle. What I did was just let Android Studio be the one to update the gradle on the first build.

After that my app runs and builds without any issues.

Hope this helps.